# why is reshape(4,2) different from reshape(2,-1).T for a 2x2x2 matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I tried the following snippet

```
a = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]],[[5, 6], [7, 8]]])
b = a.reshape(2,-1).T
c = a.reshape(4,2)
```

I thought the b and c would be the same since a is getting reshaped to a 4x2 matrix. But they are not. Here is b and c

```
[[1 5]
 [2 6]
 [3 7]
 [4 8]]

[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]
 [7 8]]
```

why did the arrangement change?

Comment: In `b` its getting shaped as a 2 x 4 matrix, thats not the same as a 4 x 2 matrix

Comment: Transpose changes effective memory layout, reshape does not.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the operations you are performing.

```
>>> a = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]],[[5, 6], [7, 8]]])
>>> a
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])
```

This gets the 4,2 shape you wanted

```
>>> a.reshape(4,2)
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

This gets you 2 rows and 4 columns

```
>>> a.reshape(2,-1)
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Applying the .T operator switches your rows to columns:

```
>>> a.reshape(2,-1).T
array([[1, 5],
       [2, 6],
       [3, 7],
       [4, 8]])
```

To reshape to a 4, 2 array using -1 for a dimension it needs to be in the first position to achieve a 4, 2 array:

```
>>> a.reshape(-1,2)
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```